# JDBC returns null value in resultSet using where condition. I tried to get all columns but its not returning any value

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, where-clause

I want to get all the data from the database using a where condition. But resultSet returning null values. But when I use an Integer instead of string it works fine, but that I don't want.

I'm not many experts in SQL but when I run a query in SQL server it works fine.

```
public JSONObject searchInternship1(String Category) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet result;

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject mainObject1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {

        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@144.217.163.57:1521:XE", "mad310team2", "anypw");
        String sql;

        sql = ("SELECT * FROM INTERNSHIP WHERE CATEGORY= ?");

        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        // con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
        stmt.setString(1, Category);
        result = stmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("resultttt   " + result);
        String status;

        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        long time = instant.getEpochSecond();

        if (result.next() == false) {
            status = "Failed";
            mainObject1.accumulate("Status :", status);
            mainObject1.accumulate("Timestamp :", time);
            mainObject1.accumulate("Message :", " Fetching Failed");
            mainObject1.accumulate("why not", Category);

            // System.out.println("hellooooo  "+ result);
        } else {
            do {
                mainObject1.accumulate("why not111", Category);
                status = "Success";
                jsonObject.accumulate("Id :", result.getInt("INT_ID"));
                jsonObject.accumulate("CONTACT PERSON", result.getString("CONTACT_PERSON"));
                jsonObject.accumulate("INCENTIVE", result.getString("INCENTIVE"));
                jsonObject.accumulate(" VENUE", result.getString("VENUE"));
                jsonObject.accumulate("DATE OF TEST", result.getDate("DATE_OF_TEST").toString());
                jsonObject.accumulate("DATE OF TEST", result.getString("TIME_OF_TEST"));
                jsonObject.accumulate("PROCEDURE", result.getString("PROCEDUREE"));
                jsonObject.accumulate("No. OF VACANCIES", result.getInt("NO_OF_VACANCIES"));
                jsonObject.accumulate("COMPANY ID", result.getInt("COMPANY_ID"));
                jsonObject.accumulate("CATEGORY", result.getString("CATEGORY"));
                jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
                jsonObject.clear();
            } while (result.next());

            // result = result + r.getString("data");
            mainObject1.accumulate("Details of jobs: ", jsonArray);
        }
        stmt.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //   System.out.println("Error at111:" + ex.getClass().getName() + ex.getMessage());

        Logger.getLogger(Register_Detail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }

    return mainObject1;
}

@GET
@Path("searchInternship&{value1}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String searchInternship(@PathParam("value1") String Category)
        throws SQLException {


    JSONObject result = searchInternship1(Category);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Not related to you problem, but your code should not call `DriverManager.registerDriver`, that method is to be called by JDBC driver implementations, not by normal code.

Comment: When you say 'resultSet returning null value', does this mean your `searchInternship1` method returns (a) `null`, (b) an array of `null`s, (c) an array of empty objects, (d) an array of objects, each of whose properties has a `null` value, or (e) something else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a JDBC issue.  I believe this is an issue with how you are reading the data out of the result set.

At the top of your `createInternship1` method you create a JSONObject object.  Let's suppose at least one row comes back from the result set.  For the first row read from the result set, your code then reads the values out of the result set and writes them into your JSONObject, before adding your JSONObject to your JSON array `jsonArray`.

So far, your code is doing what you want it to.  You have a JSON array with a single object in it, containing the data read from the first row in the result set.   However, the problem comes with your next step.

You then clear your JSONObject.

Your array doesn't contain a copy of your JSONObject, it contains *the same* object.

So at this point, your array now contains a single empty JSONObject.  The data you read out of the result set has been deleted.

As your code proceeds through further rows in the result set, it encounters another problem.  It reads more data into the same JSONObject created earlier, adds this same JSONObject (which is already in the array) to the array and then clears this same JSONObject again.  You therefore end up with a JSON array containing the same empty JSONObject once for each row read from the result set.

I figured you're using the json-simple library for handling JSON.  Initially I thought you were using org.json, but the JSONObject class in that library doesn't have a `clear()` method, whereas json-simple's JSONObject class does have this method.  json-simple's JSONObject class extends `java.util.HashMap`, and calling the `get()` method of a `HashMap` returns `null` for a key that is not in the map.  Your one JSONObject is empty, so no keys are in the map, and so `null` will always be returned from any call to the `get()` method of this object.  This hopefully explains why you are getting null values returned.

You can fix this by creating a new JSONObject for each iteration of your `do ... while` loop instead of once at the top, adding that to your JSON array, and removing the line that clears the JSON object:

```
        do {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();         // add this line
            mainObject1.accumulate("why not111", Category);
            status = "Success";
            jsonObject.accumulate("Id :", result.getInt("INT_ID"));
            jsonObject.accumulate("CONTACT PERSON", result.getString("CONTACT_PERSON"));

            // ... various similar lines omitted for clarity

            jsonObject.accumulate("CATEGORY", result.getString("CATEGORY"));
            jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
        } while (result.next());
```

You'll also need to delete the line `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();` further up in your code.

Comment: I fixed the issue... Thank You everyone